# Tomcat - Two Way SSL as Server

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm trying to implement two way SSL on a new web service that we are building and I'm having some issues.

First some info on  the environment.

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Server built:   Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
Server number:  8.0.36.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_111-b14
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

We use an internal certificate authority to sign all of our certificates. So all the client certificates are signed by our internal root. When I trust the root certificate in the client trust store everything works. All client certificates signed by the internal root work.

However, if I remove the root certificate from the client trust store, and add individual client certificates instead I get a cert chain error.

---

```
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 107108750176335210433834926983330116805775068919227166974389735341685270962458
  public y coord: 93195725734236902743006469378087068209149058097948526490562555560744449337507
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA Cert Authorities:
<CN=Client, OU=Information Technology, O=Company, L=Calgary, ST=Alberta, C=CA>
*** ServerHelloDone
http-nio2-8443-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4482 http-nio2-8443-exec-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 7
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
http-nio2-8443-exec-2, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain %% Invalidated:[Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
http-nio2-8443-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate http-nio2-8443-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2 http-nio2-8443-exec-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain http-nio2-8443-exec-2, called closeOutbound() http-nio2-8443-exec-2, closeOutboundInternal()
```

This is an issue for us as we can't have all the client certificates in the company granted access to this endpoint, it kind of defeats the purpose.

The company root certificate is in another trust store used on server startup. Here are my configs.

Server.xml connector:

```
   <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="24" minSpareThreads="4" maxSpareThreads="4" acceptCount="1000" server=" "
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="certs/servercert.jks" keystorePass=" CrazyPasswordHere"
           clientAuth="true" truststoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/certs/clienttrust.jks" truststorePass="CrazyPasswordHere"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" sslProtocol="TLS"
           ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
           useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true" compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript" />
```

Systemd init:

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/usr/local/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/local/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS= -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8090 \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/jmxremote.password \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/jmxremote.access \ -Djavax.net.debug=SSL \ -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/local/tomcat/certs/servertrust.jks \ -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=CrazyPasswordHere \ -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/usr/local/tomcat/certs/serverclient.jks \ -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=CrazyPasswordHere '
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any input here would be great! I can't imagine that the solution here is that every client cert signed by a specific authority is supposed to have access...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic. You are conflating authentication with authorization. It is the job of SSL to authenticate via the mechanism you have already set up, and which as you say is working perfectly. It is the job of Tomcat, or the application, to use that information to define who is authorized to use the webapp. This is done via web.xml, CMA, etc.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct. I shouldn't have been enabling clientauth in my connector string, but rather in my web.xml. I now have this setup and working nicely.